# Create function not recognized on user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following classes in my model:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
      has_one :list
   end
```

and

```
   class List < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
   end
```

Now I want to create a new list button on my list/show page where I can create a new list for a current_user.

```
  def new
    @list = List.new
  end


  def create
    @list = current_user.list.build(params.require(:list).permit(:title))

      if @list.save
      redirect_to @list, notice: "List was saved successfully."
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error creating list. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end
```

But something goes wrong in my create function. I makes sense cause also when I open rails c and try:

```
u = User.first => validated user
u = List.new
```

I get the error that list is not method for u (my user). What goes wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide information about error, but I guess interpreter complains about calling `build` method on `nil`. It's because you call:

```
@list = current_user.list.build(params.require(:list).permit(:title))
```

but `current_user.list` returns `nil`. You should have this instead:

```
@list = current_user.build_list(params.require(:list).permit(:title))
```

Documentation for [`has_one`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one) method

Comment: @user3706202 did it help? If not, what's the exact error message?